# Passing through certain M-<key> command to OS in Emacs

Tags: macos, emacs, hotkeys

Is there a way to pass a certain M-key combination to the OS? I'm using OSX and I'd like to have the "Move focus to next window in application" key which I use to work also in Emacs, currently it just says that M- is undefined (the key combo works in other apps, I use CMD as meta).

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to switch between the frames with the same command as I have configured OSX to use (CMD-§).

I just added this to init.el:

(global-set-key (kbd "M-§") 'other-frame)

So I don't need to "pass this" to OS, because this will have the exact same effect.

Comment: The problem with this solution is when I have multiple spaces: OSX behaviour is that Cmd+` (or cmd+§) cycles through open windows in the same space. If I have Emacs frames open on different spaces, other-frame command cycles through all of them, switching spaces as needed.

Comment: What if you don't want to go to another emacs frame, but just want to move to the next app.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about using `CMD-~`? If so, emacs has similar functionality with the following keystrokes:

```
C-x <LEFT>
Select the previous buffer in the list of existing buffers. 
C-x <RIGHT>
Select the next buffer in the list of existing buffers.
```

See [how to change buffers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Select-Buffer.html) in the documentation. FWIW, `C-h a` will let you search the help system for any keywords you'd like.

Comment: My question is a bit unclear: I meant frames not buffers. Anyway, I found an alternative way (see my own answer :)